# switching off or on the parts of the general settings on gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, backup, settings, gitlab-ce

After removing the directory of Gitlab unintentionally, I had to restore a backup I had.
But after restoring the backup I can't switch off or on the parts of the general settings like Issues, Repository, Merge requests, and so on about previous projects and I encounter to this error: "Something went wrong on our end."

[image]
[image]

I don't know how I can fix it. there are someone who can help me?